# Does denying port access to an EC2 instance prevent DDOS? What happens to the request?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ddos

I have an EC2 instance that I want to implement request rate limiting. So in my MVC controllers I have rate limiting code to prevent http DDOS attacks at the HTTP level. The code rejects request after predefined requests/sec, minute etc...

I thought I would take it a step further and not just deny the request on the server but put a deny firewall rule at the AWS network level. What happens to a server/AWS infrastructure if someone tries to flood a port with a request that I put in a deny rule for? I understand obviously that it gets blocked. How does AWS infrastructure handle all the denied requests? Let's say that port gets attacked and I start denying a large list of IPs will it be handled properly. It's a bit confusing if this is a feasible solution and is there any billing issues involved. I'm looking to AWS shield to prevent SYN attacks and other lower layer but want a deny list of my own that I can track and audit for the HTTP level. This way I can manage differentiating legitimate high traffic customers from attackers.

Comment: Check out AWS WAF... It will handle all this and can give you the logs that you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I would still like the question answered about deny on the firewall rules and what happens. I just put an example for context. There are many reasons I may not want to use WAF and wanted to know the technical implications of my questions. I am aware of WAF. To emphasize, this is only for web applications. I may want to expose other services publicly that are not web servers. There are cost implications as well .

Comment: Also please remember that WAF requires cloudfront. I want to know what happens to EC2 instances as I may expose other services (MSSQL etc). In short does the AWS network hardware handle absorbing rejected connnections and is it powerful enough and load balanced to thwart an attack on a specific instance. I don't want to use any load balancer either as it adds costs I don't want to incur for my users.

Comment: Of course, the overall AWS infrastructure can handle virtually any DDoS attack; its one of the largest, most sophisticated, most advanced networks and infrastructures in the world. Of course the AWS infrastructure can thwart an attack on a specific instance, but just like how a seat belt can only protect you if you’re wearing it, AWS’s built in protections (like Shield Standard) can only protect you if you architect your application according to best practices, including the use of CloudFront and Route53.

Comment: For your question specifically: if you DROP the connection it will wait to timeout. If you REJECT then it will send an RST packet and close the connection. If this is a serious concern then you would be strongly advised to use CloudFront, Route53, and WAF to protect yourself... The cost is negligible compared to the cost of responding to a production DDoS incident.

Comment: @samman WAF does not require CloudFront.  Application Load Balancer -- which you should be using if you are interested in a resilient architecture, since it operates at layer 7 and does not use 1:1 front-to-back connections except for web sockets -- also supports WAF.  https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/12/AWS-WAF-now-available-on-Application-Load-Balancer/

Comment: @hephalump. I guess you guys keep giving me solutions that I know are great but my question is for a simplistic situation. I have a customer who has access to a sql server for example and I don't allow any other IP address but theirs. If the attack is launched on that IP would my server be safe assuming your saying the AWS infrastructure is advanced.  Will it absorb it or am I really going to need some WAF or NLB/ALB type solution as a proxy. For example is the infrastructure for a specific instance only for that instance (aka smart routers they are utilizing) or for several instances.

Comment: Maybe it is better I ask Amazon and post it here. I don't believe in complicating a scenario. Opening up a specific port for a client vs needing load balancers with SSL certificates and other overhead/costs. For a website/api I could understand other solutions. I'm assuming it is safe but I can't tell the customer I assumed after a DDOS attack on a server that should pretty much be private and only whitelisted to them not the public!! In other words your solutions make sense for public facing infrastructure (websites/api) not a single instance for a few or one customer with specific IP access.

Comment: @sqlbot WAF is for web applications. I am solving several scenarios. One of them is MSSQL servers that are not HTTP based. So there is Network Load Balancing.